# Html no working well with visual studio code

Tags: html, visual-studio, attributes

I need help for some reason when it comes to getting the meaning of a tag or attribute in HTML visual studio code it does not show up can someone help me out, please.
[image]

Comment: Don't post code as a picture.

Comment: hello am looking for help am not posting code but showing the error if you look at type why isnt the meaing or doctype comeing up?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html) on Visual Studio Code, **you can hover over the code to see the meaning**. However, I think the feature you are talking about is more suited for interpreted languages such as Python.

Comment: Can you give me a good ide because for both python and html css flask as i try atom i dont like the fact that debugging feature in the baby stage.

Comment: Yeah, any text editor can be customized for programming. However, I would recommend **Sublime Text** because it is fast, easy to use and set up. Check out this video on [setting up sublime for Flask](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwZwr5Tvyxo) .